# how to post array of generic objects in retrofit

Tags: java, kotlin, retrofit

I Have this JSON , needed it to post on the server , the problem how we send array of generic objects

```
  "items": [
            {
                "variant": {
                    "id": 48,
                    "quantity": "1"
                },
                "custom_form_data": {
                    "features": {
                        "delivery_email": "haw@ogloba.com",
                        "delivery_mobile": "+886970639636"
                    },
                    "customer_info": "TEST Han Customer Info"
                }
            }
        ],
```

this is the call

```
 items = arrayOf(
                        Variant(id = 48, quantity = "1"),
                        CustomFormData(features = Features("haw@ogloba.com", "+886970639636") ,customerInfo = "inof")
                    ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a data class for that format, something like this:

```
data class Item (
   val variant: Variant,
   val custom_form_data: CustomFormData
)
```

And then in your retrofit ApiService interface definition:

```
interface ApiService {

   @POST('url')
   fun methodName(): List<Item>

}
```